# Database structure

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following fields of data to store on a table :

```
Person ID
Person Interested Programme (can be an 1, 2, 3, 4 or a combination of these numbers)
Person Skills (can be 3-4 skills)
Person Backgrounds (can be 2 backgrounds)
Country
```

Is it better to store things like skills & backgrounds in an array or should I store them in different tables?

I have a programme that will calculate show this information on Map according to specific filters based on skills and backgrounds.

Just looking for feedback on the most efficient structure.

Comment: In general, if you need to store "1-n" of something, in a relational database, that means having a separate **table** for those things connected to your main entity. Most relational databases don't have any support for arrays - if you need multiple of somethings - put those "something" in a tbale

Comment: I see, thank you for the advice. I will go ahead and do just that!

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you need to store "1-n" of something, in a relational database, that means having a separate table for those things connected to your main entity. Most relational databases don't have any support for arrays - if you need multiple of somethings - put those "something" in a table